# TSQL : Issue in converting 24 hour time into AM PM

Tags: sql-server, function, t-sql, time

I have made a function to convert the 24 hour time (for e.g 0900 to 9 am). Here is the function.

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @ret varchar(10);
DECLARE @temp varchar(10);
DECLARE @tempHH varchar(10);
DECLARE @AMPM varchar(10);

DECLARE @tempHours int;

Set @ret = cast(@timing as varchar);
Set @temp = @ret;


if len(@timing) = 3
begin
    set @ret = '0' + cast(left(@temp,1) as varchar(5)) + ':'
    set @ret = @ret + right(@temp,2) + ' AM';
end -- if len = 3

if len(@timing) = 4
begin
    Set @tempHours = cast(left(@temp,2) as int);
    set @AMPM = ' AM';

    if @tempHours > 12
    begin
        set @AMPM = ' PM';
        set @tempHours = @tempHours - 12;

    end

    if len(@tempHours)=1
        set @ret = '0'+ cast(@tempHours as varchar(5)) + ':'
    else
        set @ret = cast(@tempHours as varchar(5)) + ':'

    set @ret = @ret + right(@temp,2) + @AMPM;
end --length = 4

if len(@ret)=2
    set @ret = '00:'+ @ret;
return @ret;

END
```

It works fine, for all times except for 1200 to 1259. For e.g it shows "12:30 AM" for 1230, or "12:10 AM" for 1210 etc, where as it should show "12:30 PM" and "12:10 PM" respectively. How can i solve this?

Comment: 1325 is 1.25PM, why do you think it's 1.25AM?

Comment: I don't see a single datetime-typed variable in your code. Dates (or times) have no format. Format is used only when converting from/to text.  Use `datetime` variables and format them as strings using `CONVERT` or `FORMAT` with the proper format modifiers

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The problem is the value stored in the db from which im picking the time is stored in a string, so my function converts simple values, like 1230 or 0090 etc to AM PM times.

Comment: How is `@timing` (presumably, the input value) actually defined?

Comment: @user3176971 cast the stored value to the appropriate type (`time`, `datetime`) then convert it to the desired format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace the code:

```
if @tempHours > 12
    begin
        set @AMPM = ' PM';
        set @tempHours = @tempHours - 12;
    end
```

with:

```
if @tempHours >= 12
    set @AMPM = ' PM';

if @tempHours > 12
    set @tempHours = @tempHours - 12;
```

Comment: If you tried this you would notice that `1230` turns into `00:30 PM` which is wrong as it should be `12:30 PM`.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** I realized from comments that you get 4 digits without the semicolon, so I used `STUFF` to put a semi-colon in the middle.

If you know that you're going to get a 3 or 4 digit number, consider converting it to a date, and back to string?

```
Declare @TimeString VarChar (10) = '1325'

Set @TimeString = Stuff (@TimeString, Len (@TimeString) -1, 0, ':')

Select Right (Replace (Convert (VarChar, cast ('01/01/1900 ' + @TimeString  as datetime), 131), ':00:000', ''), 7) as ConvertedValue
```

Output

```
ConvertedValue
--------------
 1:25PM

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Since the longest string that the OP checks is 4 chars I think it's safe to assume that the original value is stored as `1325` without the semi-colon, and if so this solution breaks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you treat hours 1200-1259 as `< 12` and thus never change to PM.

Add this condition before `if @tempHours > 12` to make `1200-1259` -> PM :

```
if @tempHours = 12
begin
    set @AMPM = ' PM';
end
```

The result for the value`1210`will be`12:10 PM`.

Comment: @entropic Because it would give incorrect results as the if block for `> 12`includes a subtraction. 12 is a special case and can not be treated as > 12.

Comment: Gotcha - that's what I get for reading up to the if and not what's contained within it.

Answer (score 0):

I would convert the input into an `int` (if you've not already) and then do some simple maths on it, before asking SQL Server to reformat it into a string.

```
declare @timing int
set @timing = 1205

select RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(20),
        DATEADD(hour,@timing/100,
        DATEADD(minute,@timing%100,0))
    ,100),7)
```

Result:

```
-------
12:05PM
```

Answer (score 0):

If the value were stored in the [24-hour format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock) (ie including the time separator), you could cast to `time` then convert to an AM/PM format, eg:

```
declare @timing varchar(5)='18:02'

declare @time time=cast(@timing as time)
select convert(varchar(50),@time,100)

Result:
----------
6:02PM
```

Your values are stored using the [military format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock#Military_time) which has no separator but can be easily cast to an integer. In this case, hundreds correspond to hours while the modulo by 100 corresponds to minutes.

In SQL Server 2012+ you can use [TIMEFROMPARTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213398.aspx) to create a `time` value from its parts:

```
declare @timing varchar(4)='1802'

declare @value int=cast(@timing as int)
declare @time time=TIMEFROMPARTS(@value/100,@value % 100,0,0,0)

select convert(varchar(50),@time,100)

Result:
----------
6:02PM
```

If you use `802` or `0802` you'll get `8:02AM`.

In previous versions you can construct a valid time string, then cast and convert. You can convert to int as before, or you can split the string as in this example:

```
declare @timing varchar(4)='1802'

declare @value varchar(5)=  STUFF(@timing,LEN(@timing)-1,0,':')
declare @time time=cast(@value as time)

select convert(varchar(50),@time,100)
```

Finally, you can insert a space before the AM/PM string with [STUFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx):

```
declare @timing varchar(4)='1802'

declare @value varchar(5)=  STUFF(@timing,LEN(@timing)-1,0,':')
declare @time time=cast(@value as time)
declare @ampm varchar(6)=convert(varchar(6),@time,100)  

select STUFF(@ampm,LEN(@ampm)-1,0,' ')

Result:
--------
6:02 PM
```